# FactoryGirl Test Failure - Trying to Build an Association to Itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to use FactoryGirl to create a self-associated object to use for testing a simple tree of categories.  I've read through [FactoryGirl's Getting Started doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) for setting up assocations, but still having an issue.  I'd like to test that an object has a parent, and a child (1 child since that's the setup in my FactoryGirl definition).  My test for a parent passes, but fails on testing for a child

ERROR message

```
1) Category should have a child
   Failure/Error: category.children.count.should eq(1)

     expected: 1
          got: 0
```

RSPEC tests

```
it "should have a child" do
    category = FactoryGirl.build(:parent_category)

    category.should_not be_nil

    category.children.count.should eq(1)
end

it "should have a parent" do
    category = FactoryGirl.build(:child_category)

    category.should_not be_nil

    category.parent.should_not be_nil
end
```

MODEL setup for a parent / child relationship (of the same Model):

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id', :dependent => :destroy

  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id

  validates :name, :presence => true

  before_validation :uppercase_name

  def uppercase_name
    self.name.upcase! unless self.name.nil?
  end
end
```

FACTORYGIRL setup:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :category do
    name "CATEGORY"

    factory :parent_category do
      name "PARENT"
      parent_id 0
      after(:create) do |pc, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:category, 1, parent: pc)
      end
    end

    factory :child_category do
      name "CHILD"
      association :parent, factory: :parent_category
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

We ended up using [closure_tree](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree)
because of the concurrency issues with awesome_nested_set

Answer (score 0):

I found a promising gem called [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) it appears to serve a very DRY purpose.

And another interesting tree gem called [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry).